# Imprimir (print) uma lista de dicionários

Tags: python, lista, dicionário, print

Criei um dicionário para cara linha de um arquivo e depois os inseri numa lista. A forma que extraí foi:

```
pessoas = []
with open('pessoas.txt') as ficheiro:
    texto = ficheiro.readlines()
    tag = {'id': [], 'nome': [], 'apelido': [], 'nascimento': []}
    keys = list(tag.keys())
    contador = 0
    while contador < 4:
        for line in texto:
            values = texto[contador].strip().split(';')
            pessoas.append(dict(zip(keys, values)))
            contador += 1
```

A lista `pessoas` ficou assim:

```
[{'id': '1', 'nome': 'Carlos', 'apelido': 'Pérez', 'nascimento': '05/01/1989'},
{'id': '2', 'nome': 'Manuel', 'apelido': 'Heredia', 'nascimento': '26/12/1973'},
{'id': '3', 'nome': 'Rosa', 'apelido': 'Campos', 'nascimento': '12/06/1961'},
{'id': '4', 'nome': 'David', 'apelido': 'García', 'nascimento': '25/07/2006'}]
```

Agora gostaria de um print disso de uma forma mais "amigável", por exemplo:

```
(id=1) Carlos Pérez => 05/01/1989
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for p in pessoas:
    print("(id={id}) {nome} {apelido} => {nascimento}".format(**p))
```

Explicação:

- Laço `for` percorre todos os dicionários dentro da lista `pessoas`.
- Imprime cada dicionário com `print` combinado com o método `format` para posicionar o conteúdo.
- Como toda a informação está em um dicionário, usa-se o operador `**` para desempacotá-lo e deixar a chamada ao `print` mais compacta e legível.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um [print formatado](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp):

```
print("(id={}) {} {} => {}".format(item['id'], item['nome'], item['apelido'], item['nascimento']))
```

As chaves `{}` são substituídas pelos valores passados como parâmetros no método `format`.
Mais detalhes sobre o uso do método `String.format` no link associado acima.